# socket.io connection still exists after disconnection

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to forward message from Redis pubsub to socketio client by using nodejs EventEmitter.

```
  var events = require('events');
  var subscriber = redis.createClient();

  var app = express();

  var localEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();


  var server = require('http').createServer(app);

  var io = require("socket.io")(server, {secure: 'true'});

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    localEmitter.on('FORWARDING', function(message)) {
      console.log(socket.id + ': localEmitter is forwarding messages');
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log(socket.id + ' disconnected);
    })
  };


  subscriber.on('message', function (channel, message) {

      console.log("Got message from redis");
      localEmitter.emit('FORWARDING', encoded);
  });
```

But if I refresh the webpage, the websocket connection disconnects and reconnects, the `disconnect` method can be triggered, but the `localEmitter` still forwarding messages via the old socket id.

The logs look like:

```
pxw8pcocxI3O2ru3AAAA: localEmitter is forwarding message
0BX2bVYoAn2g2JtMAAAB: localEmitter is forwarding message
0BX2bVYoAn2g2JtMAAAB disconnected
pxw8pcocxI3O2ru3AAAA: localEmitter is forwarding message
0BX2bVYoAn2g2JtMAAAB: localEmitter is forwarding message
...
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong because localEmitter will always listen to the emitter. So here you need to track the sockets which are still connecting.

Comment: @CharanjeetSingh Thanks, is there a way I can remove the disconnected sockets from localEmitter?

Comment: First Please share your full problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove event emitter when socket disconnects

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  localEmitter.on('FORWARDING', mymessage);

  function mymessage(message) {
    console.log(socket.id + ': localEmitter is forwarding messages');
  }

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    localEmitter.removeListener('FORWARDING', mymessage);
    console.log(socket.id + ' disconnected');
  });

});
```

You can also use the concept of room for the same.

Comment: The problem with above code is that it's removing listener for all sockets. not only for one socket id.

Comment: At my end it is working fine removing only the particular socket.